# Is it good practice to store a customers postal address in a cookie?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am creating an e-commerce page that uses a guest checkout approach (No customer accounts). Part of the checkout process will get a customers email address, phone number, billing address & shipping address. I am trying to avoid using a session variable for this.

I understand that cookies should not store sensitive information, and I understand why.. However, is it considered good or bad practice to store a customers billing and shipping address in a cookie?

I'm using PHP if that helps.

Comment: What's wrong with using session variables?

Comment: Do you make HTTPS obligatory for transport?

Comment: for how long you want to store the address?

Comment: @MIchael Mior : I want to take as much load off of the shared server that the site will be hosted.

Comment: @WTP : I want to keep it somewhere because when the user edits the cart in the middle of the checkout process, this information will be lost if I simple store it in hidden form fields.

Comment: @hakre : Yes.. HTTPS will be implemented

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to keep that information at all in a cookie or session. Simply store it in the database if you want to keep it and keep the key in session/hidden field/querystring (likely not the best as that's directly visible in the address bar).

Cookies get sent back and forth with each request so either don't make too much use of them and don't put too much information in them either. Especially when it's containing sensitive data which can be intercepted.

Update after first comment: In case you would not want to keep the data in the database then you need to have a trigger or process flow that sweeps afterwards. In ASP.NET, when storing session state in SQL Server, this is done by a SQL Agent job that runs every minute and takes out abandoned sessions. You didn't specify which database engine you're using but it would surely have something similar. If not then you can use a task scheduler or cron job to periodically call a page that executes some cleaning up code.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I considered it but should I be concerned with  deleting any of these unused rows in the db table?? For ex. if a guest  starts the checkout process and then leaves the site without making a purchase.. would it be important to remove that unused row from the table?

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no reason not to encrypt the cookie, you could even get rid of php's session altogether and store everything in an encrypted cookie. This way the session variables are not dependant on a specific server machine. The only downside I can see is the 4KB limit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using it just to pass it from one page to another, use sessions (or even hidden form input fields), no reason to use cookies. And if you use it for returning users - why don't you just store all the user data in the database?

Comment: It is a guest checkout only. The problem is that when the user wants to edit the cart in the middle of the checkout process, this info will be lost if I just use the hidden form technique.  I probably will go with a "temporary db storage".

Comment: I see. But it won't be lost if, for example, you put users enter it in the first page, then, on the second page, you read $_POST variables and put them in the hidden form that will be then sent to the next page, etc... until you reach checkout. Makes sense?  This might be subjective, but I wouldn't feel like doing that with a db of any kind - cookies are fine that way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in PHP data about session stores exactly in cookies (with some encryption), so why you do not want to use it?

Comment: In PHP, session data is stored on the server -- the cookie just contains a session ID.